# How can I "recreate" a nilpotent operator given a Jordan matrix with just zeroes on diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I have been given a problem where for an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$, a vector space $\dim{V}=n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ ,
$$ 0 <n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_{k-1},n_k=n$$
A sequence of integers, whereas $n_0\triangleq{0}$,

You'd need to prove the existence of a linear map $T:V\to V$ s.t. $n_i=\dim\ker\left(T^i\right),\ \forall{i\in\left[k\right]}$.

I have managed to find a Jordan matrix $M_n\left(\mathbb{F}\right)$, whose Jordan blocks' main diagonals consist of nothing but zeroes, for which the linear map:
$$T_A:\mathbb{F^n}\to\mathbb{F^n},\ \ \vec{x}\mapsto{A\vec{x}}$$

Satisfies the requirements (including $n_i=\dim\ker\left({T_A}^i\right),\ \forall{i\in\left[k\right]}$), other than $T_A$ obviously not being $V\to{V}$.

It'd seem somewhat trivial, that you'd be able to find some nilpotent operator $T:V\to{V}$ whose Jordan normal form is $A$,

Whereas
$$n_i=\dim\ker\left({T_A}^i\right),\ \forall{i\in\left[k\right]}\implies{n_i=\dim\ker\left({T}^i\right),\ \forall{i\in\left[k\right]}}$$

But I'm very much stuck and cannot figure out a way to do this?

Is it possible that I'm wrong?
If not, how do I go about turning a Jordan matrix with nothing but zeroes on the diagonal into a nilpotent operator of $V$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know whether I understand you. But does this help: Let $S:V\to\mathbb{F}^n$ be an isomorphism (a "choose a basis" isomorphism); then $T=S T_A S^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely it in that regard.
However, I think I might have found a bad matrix that doesn't actually satisfy the requirements.
Do you have a clue on what an appropriate matrix for this question might be?

Comment: If you write down a matrix with $a_i$ Jordan $i\times i$ blocks for $i=1\dots n$ then it is easy to write down $r(A),r(A^2),\dots$ in terms of the $a_i$, and also (RN Thm) in terms of the $n_i$. The equations solve prettily easily I think.